# C# Task Run Cancellation Token cleanup after cancellation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

How do I do some cleanup after checking if the cancellation token has been canceled but what I've found is if I try to do anything it the below code, everything works as expected except the cancellation, as soon as await LeaveGroup(SIGNALR_NETWORK_TEST_GROUP); is called the thread ends and nothing after it happens I've tried several different calls and it doesn't matter it just ends immediately instead of waiting for me to clean things up before I return.

What am I missing here?  I even found a couple of examples from Microsoft that lead me to believe I'm on the right track but it doesn't let me execute anything else after I've checked if it's been canceled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-cancellation-requests-by-polling

```
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            var signalRClient = new SignalRClient();
            Task.Run(async () => await signalRClient.Start(cancellationToken), cancellationToken);

            Console.ReadKey();
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public async Task Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var signalRConnectionInfo = await GetConnectionInfo();

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(signalRConnectionInfo.Url, options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(signalRConnectionInfo.AccessToken);
            })
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string>("OnUpdate", param =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(param);
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();

        if (hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
            await JoinGroup(SIGNALR_NETWORK_TEST_GROUP);


        while (hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cancellation Requested!");
                await LeaveGroup(SIGNALR_NETWORK_TEST_GROUP);
                throw new OperationCanceledException("SignalR connection cancelled!", cancellationToken);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your application ends after you call cancel. this may or may not be your specific problem, but it **IS** definitely a problem

Comment: Also you are doing this,  `Task.Run(async () => ` which looks suspicious anyway... if you want wait for something to happen, you need to **NOT* offload the Task, and most likely await it after you call cancel (maybe). I think you need to start with `static async Task Main()`

Comment: I want to be able to cancel the task, the task should run until it's canceled and when it's canceled I'd like the task to clean up after itself before it ends.  That's the goal.  I don't want it to wait for it to finish or be canceled either it should keep going on to other things  When I press a key I want it to then cancel the task but still allow the task to clean up.  How I'm doing Task.Run was the only way I could figure out how to call the method on the class and pass in the cancellation token.

Comment: Even https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation leads me to think I'm doing it correctly in their example they do some cleanup and then ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); but anything I do as cleanup the thread ends.

Comment: Another example which leads me to believe I'm doing ti right https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-cancellation-requests-by-polling but again doesn't work for me.

Comment: Take a look at this: [A Tour of Task, Part 9: Delegate Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html), and especially the section **CancellationToken**. It talks about `Task.Factory.StartNew`, but `Task.Run` behaves exactly the same regarding the `CancellationToken` parameter.